# Round somes corners only

Tags: modeling, workflow

I would like to round corners (surrounded in red) of this shape:

[image: My too angular shape]

I tried some options:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> : this does not work on the surrounded vertices.
- Subsurf. It look like I can use this technique but it increase the polygons significantly. But if this is the only solution I'll use it

Comment: reminds me of http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/images/0/07/Cupola.PNG

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Temporarily extrude edges

You’ll be able to round the corners with the bevel tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) by extruding the boundary loop just to feed Blender with some faces to work with and then deleting the extrusion.

[image: Extrude in the Z direction, select the edges at the corners of the extrusion, Ctrl+B then scroll to round the corners, then select the top edge loop and delete vertices.]

Comment: Thank you, this technique fit m problem.
I also found another technique watching this speed modeling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VvvqAEgbJs

It use boolean tool to combine shapes. I can post the gif to show an example but I don't no how to make it :)